# Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: '(4708, 4717, 'Companies worked at')' and '(4681, 4717, 'Degree')'

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, resume

[enter image description here][1]

Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: '(4708, 4717, 'Companies worked at')' and '(4681, 4717, 'Degree')'. A token can only be part of one entity, so make sure the entities you're setting don't overlap. To work with overlapping entities, consider using doc.spans instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spacy:Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: A token can only be part of one entity, so make sure the entities you're setting don't overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63620691/spacytrying-to-set-conflicting-doc-ents-a-token-can-only-be-part-of-one-entity)

Answer (score 2):

The EntityRecognizer does not support overlapping entities.
To solve this issue, you have a couple of choices:

- Keep one of those entities
- Use two EntityRecognizers in your pipeline, one for degree and another for companies_worked_at. Then use "set_extensions" to maintain both annotations (the recognizers will overwrite each other).
- Use the SpanCategorizer instead of the EntityRecognizer (https://spacy.io/api/spancategorizer)